# What are the Remote Desktop client GUIDs, and how to get rid of them permanently?

Tags: windows, remote-desktop, windows-11

I use Microsoft Remote Desktop client daily. Gradually GUIDs start to accumulate in the "Computer" dropdown as shown on picture:

[image]

I can remove those GUIDs by searching for them in the Registry Editor, they are all located under `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Terminal Server Client\Default`:

[image]

Once I delete them from registry they are gone, but they start accumulate again in a few days.

When trying to connect to any of these I get this window:

[image]

Similar issue is mentioned [here](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/change-in-rdp-computer-names-replaced-by-uuid/150437af-8273-4490-b492-0b0a437c4dac)

I can create a script running on schedule, that checks that registry location and delete all the values that match a GUIDs regex pattern, but I'd rather get to the root cause of this and eliminate that.

Why are they created? What do they represent? What is their purpose? Which program creates them? Is it possible to stop them from being created?

**Update 1**

Microsoft Store version of Microsoft Remote Desktop is not installed.

Comment: So are you connecting to any other servers other than those 2 intranet addresses? If so edit your question to clarify the details

Comment: @Ramhound, not usually connecting to any other servers, let me know what details might be missing and I will clarify them.

Comment: So the MRUs should be addresses or server names so I am trying to understand if the GUIDs are a result of an action or something else

Comment: By default, these GUIDS are not created with normal mstsc usage. There must be something else that causes these MRU's to appear. The only way to stop this, is to figure out what creates it. I would suggest monitoring your daily tasks, and see what the last action was (that uses remote desktop technology) that spawned these GUIDs. Its likely a third party program, script or remote app.

Comment: Also, if nothing comes to mind, scan your computer for malware and viruses. This might be hacker activity.

Comment: Do those GUIDs happen to match Hyper-V VMs on your system?

Comment: @user1686 the Hyper-V feature is not enabled on the system

Answer (score 0):

A solution was offered in the post
[Change in RDP - computer names replaced by UUID?](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/change-in-rdp-computer-names-replaced-by-uuid/150437af-8273-4490-b492-0b0a437c4dac)

> Uninstall the Microsoft Store version of Microsoft Remote Desktop
> solved the issue.
>
> Seems to me the app version of Remote Desktop is conflicting with the
> desktop version of the Remote Desktop .

Comment: Microsoft Store version of Microsoft Remote Desktop is not installed. Thanks.

Comment: (1) Do you use a Microsoft account ? (2) Do the entries continue on multiplying, or do they stop when the list reaches a certain number (capped at 10)? (3) What do you have under `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Terminal Server Client\Servers`? (4) Do you see similar Guids under `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Search\RecentApps\{775B83BD-DEE7-41CF-8102-5EE010643FDC}\RecentItems`?

Comment: (1) No. (2) Hard to tell for sure, but most likely they stop. (3) Three keys with IP I used in the past, two that are seen on the original screenshot, and another one. They contain `CertHash` and `UsernameHint` values. (4) There is no `RecentApps` under `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Search`

Comment: Try to test Windows integrity by running the commands [Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/7808-use-dism-repair-windows-10-image.html) and then [sfc /scannow](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/2895-run-sfc-command-windows-10-a.html).

Comment: I run `sfc /scannow` every few months, and these symptoms continue for about a year or so. I'll do it again.

Comment: Do DISM first to compare with Microsoft.